# Is it possible to segue to a UIPageViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller

I am attempting to add a tutorial section to my application after the user logs in. When the app loads up, they will first come to a login screen and enter their credentials. Once they are verified, I want to segue to a `UIPageViewController` and show them two pages of instructions on how to use the application. However, all of my attempts at doing so have resulted in a black screen. Here is my current attempt:

```
import UIKit

class TutorialPageViewController: UIPageViewController {

    var pages: [UIViewController] = []

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.dataSource = self
        self.delegate   = self
        print("LOADING")
        let firstView = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TutorialPage1") as! TutorialPage1ViewController
        let secondView = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TutorialPage2") as! TutorialPage2ViewController
        pages = [firstView, secondView]
        let startingViewController = self.pages[0]
        let viewControllers: [UIViewController] = [startingViewController]
        self.setViewControllers(viewControllers, direction: UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection.forward, animated: true, completion: {(done: Bool) in})
    }

    func viewControllerAtIndex(index:NSInteger) -> UIViewController {
        return pages[index]
    }
}

extension TutorialPageViewController: UIPageViewControllerDataSource
{
    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {

    guard let viewControllerIndex = pages.index(of: viewController) else { return nil }

        let previousIndex = viewControllerIndex - 1

        guard previousIndex >= 0          else { return pages.last }

        guard pages.count > previousIndex else { return nil        }

        return pages[previousIndex]
    }

    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController?
    {
        guard let viewControllerIndex = pages.index(of: viewController) else { return nil }

        let nextIndex = viewControllerIndex + 1

        guard nextIndex < pages.count else { return pages.first }

        guard pages.count > nextIndex else { return nil         }

        return pages[nextIndex]
    }
}

extension TutorialPageViewController: UIPageViewControllerDelegate { }
```

The print statement in my `viewDidLoad` method is not being called, so I don't understand what I am doing wrong. I have created a push segue to `TutorialPageViewController` from the login view controller, but nothing ever loads.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Which segue are you using ? Show , because at my end it is working fine

Comment: After looking around some more I created a view controller with a container view inside and then created a view controller (of type uipageviewcontroller) and added an embed segue which is working fine. Not sure how you got it to work this way unless it was your root view controller..

Comment: Should I share my demo code ? You can check that

Comment: That would be great

Comment: Please check https://drive.google.com/open?id=1azwws3YdYSOLyCrMPxnar7s8qVO964k-

Comment: If this helps you I will post this in a GitHub repo

Comment: Makes a lot of sense. It is helpful. Thanks for your time!

Comment: Did it Helped , Shall I Post this as An Answer ?

Comment: Yeah go ahead and ill accept it

Comment: I Posted it as Answer, Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try checking the sample Project at Below GitHub Repo :

Link - https://github.com/RockinGarg/Stack_PageVC.git

Contains two Different Ways to Access

```
1. Making use of Container View and PageVC as SubView 

2. Using Segue
```